# Is it possible to redirect to a specific intent after n times of continuously matching fallback intent in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to redirect to a particular intent after n times of continuously matching default fallback intent in Dialogflow.

Comment: yes!! after default fallback intent is invoked n-times, simply call the event associated with the intent you want to redirect to.

Comment: Let me try it - Thank you

Comment: Can anyone post an actual answer to this? I'm thinking of redirecting from one intent to another, or let n=0. I'll try when I have the time, but if someone can get it first...